# Continuation Implementation in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, stl, sfinae

While playing with the concurrency features in C++11 I noticed that there wasn't any support for continuations.  I wanted to develop something similar to Tasks in The Parallel Patterns Library (PPL), where a Task can run asynchronously and execute a continuation upon completion using the 'then' member function.

I designed my class around `std::future` and `std::async`, which provides the asynchronous processing.  The function to run asynchronously accepts any number of parameters and is called using `std::async`:

```
template<typename T>
class FutureWithContinuations final
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(T)> ContinautionSignature;

    template<typename Function, typename... ArgTypes>
    FutureWithContinuations(Function&& futureFunction, ArgTypes&&... args)
        : m_continuations()
        , m_future()
    {
        // Let the concurrency runtime decide whether to run asynchronously or to defer running of the future
        auto future = std::async(std::launch::any, std::forward<Function>(futureFunction), std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
        m_future = future.share();
    }

    template<typename Function>
    void then(const Function& continuationFunction)
    {
        auto continuation = make_unique_continuation(continuationFunction, m_future);
        m_continuations.push_back(std::move(continuation));
    }

    void wait()
    {
        if (!m_future.valid())
            throw std::future_error(std::future_errc::no_state);

        m_future.wait();
        for (const auto& continuation : m_continuations)
        {
            continuation->execute();
        }
        m_continuations.clear();
    }

    T get()
    {
        return m_future.get();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IContinuation>> m_continuations;
    std::shared_future<T> m_future;
};
```

I have two types of continuations, one for when the asynchronous operation produces a result and one for when it doesn't.  Both implement an interface that specifies the API for the `FutureAndContinuations` class to use when dealing with continuations:

```
class IContinuation
{
public:
    IContinuation(){}
    virtual ~IContinuation() = default;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};
```

Template specialisation is used along with `std::enable_if` and the template parameter feature that 'substitution failure is not an error' (SFINAE) in order to differentiate between continuations that don't act on a future result (continuation function takes no parameters):

```
template<typename FutureReturnType, typename ContinuationFunction, typename SFINAE = void>
class Continuation final : public IContinuation
{
public:
    Continuation(const ContinuationFunction& continuationFn, const std::shared_future<FutureReturnType>& sharedFuture)
        : IContinuation()
        , m_continuationFn(continuationFn)
        , m_sharedFuture(sharedFuture){}

    void execute() override
    {
        m_continuationFn();
    }

private:
    ContinuationFunction m_continuationFn;
    std::shared_future<FutureReturnType> m_sharedFuture;
};
```

And continuations that do act on a future result (continuation function takes one parameter that is the result of the `std::future`):

```
template<typename FutureReturnType, typename ContinuationFunction>
class Continuation<FutureReturnType, ContinuationFunction, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<FutureReturnType>::value>::type> final : public IContinuation
{
public:
    Continuation(const ContinuationFunction& continuationFn, const std::shared_future<FutureReturnType>& sharedFuture)
        : IContinuation()
        , m_continuationFn(continuationFn)
        , m_sharedFuture(sharedFuture){}

    void execute() override
    {
        m_continuationFn(m_sharedFuture.get());
    }

private:
    ContinuationFunction m_continuationFn;
    std::shared_future<FutureReturnType> m_sharedFuture;
};
```

I have a helper function for creating continuations that the user can call without having to specify the tempalte parameter types as they can be deduced:

```
template<typename FutureReturnType, typename ContinuationFunction>
std::unique_ptr<IContinuation> make_unique_continuation(const ContinuationFunction& continuationFunction, const std::shared_future<FutureReturnType>& sharedFuture)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<IContinuation>(new Continuation<FutureReturnType, ContinuationFunction>(continuationFunction, sharedFuture));
}
```

The code was developed in Visual Studio 2013 and I used MSTest in order to validate the functionality.  The code contains explicit disabling of copying and moving in each class using delete but I have excluded those from the code snippets for the sake of brevity.  All of the code including the tests is available on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/EoghanRua/blog-work/src/cd15c3158d6ee83d225fc1f07c2494c426f6427d/C++/FuturesAndContinuations/?at=master).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what kind of feedback you're looking for here.

What you've implemented is ***not*** equivalent to what's usually called `.then()`. The usual semantics of `.then()` allow you to do things like

```
std::future<int> f = std::async([]{ return 1; });
std::future<int> g = f.then([](std::future<int> x){ return x.get() + 1; });
int v = g.get();
assert(v == 1+1);
```

What you've got, on the other hand, allows you to do something like

```
std::future<int> f = std::async([]{ return 1; });
f.then([](int x){ printf("%d\n", x); return x + 1; });
int v = f.get();  // prints "1"
assert(v == 1);   // v is not 2
```

I don't really understand why you'd want the latter semantics. Do you find them useful?

---

```
typedef std::function<void(T)> ContinautionSignature;
```

You misspelled "ContinuationSignature" here; but it doesn't matter, because the type is unused. Remove it.

---

Your class `Continuation` is merely a type-erased wrapper around a *callable*. We have a name for that in C++11 and later: it's called `std::function`. Consider:

```
template<typename FutureReturnType, typename ContinuationFunction>
std::function<void()> make_unique_continuation(
    const ContinuationFunction& continuationFunction,
    const std::shared_future<FutureReturnType>& sharedFuture)
{
    return [=]() mutable { continuationFunction(sharedFuture.get()); };
}
```

If you do this, about half of your code simply disappears!
(You'll still need to specialize and/or overload the above function a little bit to deal with `void`, but it looks like you've got the right ideas about that already.)

---

You may already be aware that in C++14, with proper library support, you can rewrite `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<FutureReturnType>::value>::type` as simply `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<FutureReturnType>>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The feedback that I am looking for issues to be highlighted and improvements/alternatives to be suggested. I don't agree with your observation at the top. The `FutureWithContinuations::then` function doesn't execute a _callable_ instantly.  It stores it for execution after waiting for the future, see `FutureWithContinuations::wait`. The fact that the class uses `std::future` is an implementation detail. A user only needs to know the return type generated from the future function, that is then passed as an argument to the continuation. The tests demonstrate usage.